# Why are irreducible projective schemes path connected by smooth curves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an irreducible projective scheme of dimension greater than $1$, not necessarily smooth. As far as I understand, any two points $x_1, x_2 \in X$ can be connected by a piecewise smooth curve i.e., there exists smooth curves $C_1,...,C_n$ in $X$ such that $C_i \cap C_{i+1} \not= \emptyset$ and $x_1 \in C_1, x_2 \in C_n$. Could somebody explain why this is the case?

Comment: First you need $\dim X>1$, otherwise you don't have enough choices of curves passing through $x_i$. Second, if $x_1$ is singular (and $\dim X>1$), it can happen that there is no smooth curve passing through $x_1$. So your statement can't hold.